# power BI or Excel - How to add a custom column based on columns in the pivot table

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop

[This is the sample of raw data. It shows the value that each of the property got on a scale of 1-10.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AATh2.png)

[Pivot Table showing count of Value on scale for each property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVHnh.png)

I want to create a custom column in a pivot table in excel or a matrix in power Bi. This column should be based on the columns in the pivot table and not on the already existing columns in the table.

Eg. I have a table with column labels from **1 to 10**  and a **Total** column. I created a pivot table to show the count of each of these columns. In the example here, Mountain has 162 values of 8, 197 values of 9 and 268 values of 10. My question is I want to create a new **custom column** which is the sum of just these three values divided by the total count. In this example , it is(162+197+268)/829 = 76%

I am not able to do it. Please help me out

Comment: Are you able to show a sample of the raw data. I'm not clear on whether the columns 1-10 are actual distinct source columns or if this is one column pivoted.

Comment: I added the raw data @BarneyL . Kindly check.
And the columns 1-10 are the values on one column which are pivoted

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI you're looking at measures something like this.

```
SurveyCount := CountRows(MyTable)
CountAllValues := CALCULATE(SurveyCount,ALL(MyTable[Value On A Scale (1-10)]))
Count8Plus :=  CALCULATE(SurveyCount,MyTable[Value On A Scale (1-10)] >= 8)
Percentage8Plus := DIVIDE(Count8Plus , CountAllValues )
```

The syntax might need a little tweak but these four should get you close to what you need.

Comment: Awesome Man. Killed it. That worked perfectly. Thanks for helping me out.